# Why is `ng-checked` not working with `ng-change`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of checkboxes. Whenever I click on a checkbox I want to call a function depending on whether it was checked or unchecked. This is achieved using `ng-change`

At the same time I also have `ng-checked` that helps me to uncheck a checkbox using a button.

Following is the implementation:

```
<md-checkbox  md-no-ink="true"  ng-checked="selected.indexOf(brand) > -1" ng-change="value?add(brand):remove(brand)" ng-model="value" ng-repeat="brand in brands">
            {{brand}}
</md-checkbox>

<md-button ng-click="fun('Spice')">Uncheck</md-button>
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
    $scope.brands = ['Apple','Samsung','Motorolla','Nokia','Micromax','Spice'];
    $scope.value = false;
    $scope.selected = [];

    $scope.fun = function(x){
        console.log("Unchecking "+x);
    }
    $scope.add = function(x){
        $scope.selected.push(x);
    }
    $scope.remove = function(x){
        var index = $scope.selected.indexOf(x);
        $scope.selected.splice(index,1);
    }
```

There is a similar question on Stackovrflow, but it had issue regarding missing ng-model on the checkboxes. I have included `ng-model` here.

Why is this not working? Have I done anything wrong ?

Comment: The ng-checked directive should NOT be used with ng-model - [see the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

Comment: oh.. I realized the issue. There is a conflict between ng-model and ng-checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) states that

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as
>   this can lead to unexpected behavior.

You should decide whether to use the `ng-model` or `ng-checked`. Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to use `ng-checked` on the `md-checkbox` directive ([see this bug](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/535)). So you will have to use the `ng-model`. The following code should help you.

**HTML**

```
<md-checkbox md-no-ink="true" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-repeat="brand in brands track by $index">
    {{brand}}
</md-checkbox>

Is Samsung selected: {{isSelected('Samsung')}}
```

**JS**

```
$scope.brands = ['Apple','Samsung','Motorolla','Nokia','Micromax','Spice'];
$scope.selected = [];

$scope.isSelected = function(brand) {
    var brandIndex = $scope.brands.indexOf(brand);
    return $scope.selected[brandIndex]
};
```

Please notice that each checkbox needs its own model. Before you used the `$scope.value` as a single model for all of the checkboxes - in such case they would be checked/unchecked all at once.

I believe the code above is what you are looking for. Feel free to make a comment if I missed the point.

Comment: Without `ng-model` is there a way for me to decide whether the checkbox was checked or unchecked?

Comment: Yes, it is if you keep using the ng-change - instead of model you use the array of brands. Let me update my answer. **UPDATE:** Aha, but you use the material design and the md-checkbox does not support `ng-checked` directive, right? Then you will have to use the `ng-model` rather than `ng-checked`. Still, let me update the answer ;).

Comment: `ng-checked` works for material design checkbox as well and I got it working! Thanks a lot for your help :-)